# How to get the IMEI from NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

How can I get the IMEI of any Android based phone from within NDK?

I dig quite a bit and could only found this:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/d00884fe886e5233?fwc=1

However it requires you to have access to the `JNIEnv` variable.

I'm working on a commercial library and can't really let the users interfere or modify the initialization.

Is there a recommended method to get access to it or?

If not, anybody can point me to some code to extract the MAC Address using NDK and pure C/C++ `ifaddr` is not available.

Comment: You can provide the HelperClass in java level and call it simply.

Answer (score 2):

The NDK isn't designed to be a complete replacement for the Java layer. There is a lot of functionality that isn't available from C except via the JNI interface.

If you're concerned about protecting access to the JNIEnv*, why not just create a helper function that your users can call, which does the JNI for them?